# Which tool to build a RPM inside a chroot?

Tags: linux, rpm, chroot, deb, pbuilder

I'm using `pbuilder` to build my binary package for Debian.

`pbuilder` creates a chroot environment, installs all the packages declared as required for the build, and then builds the binary `.deb` packages inside this chroot.

I already have my `.spec` file. I can build it. However, I have several versions of my project to build, and each have different requirements for some packages they depend on. Therefore I have to install/uninstall these dependent packages depending on which version of my project I want to build (error prone). I also cannot build in parallel if requirements are different and are supposed to be installed on the main filesystem.

I'm looking for the same kind of tool as `pbuilder` to build my binary .rpm packages.

- I've found an antique `mach` tool which looks abandoned.
- I've found `rinse` but it only does the bootstrap part.
- Also `yum-builddep` installs on the whole system, not a chroot.

Anyone knows a tool like pbuilder that resolves the dependencies and then builds an RPM inside a chroot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you’re looking for [mock](https://rpm-software-management.github.io/mock/), which takes care of setting up build chroots, installing build dependencies and building RPMs for different environments.

Comment: Simply perfect! 